# Oracle 12c default sys password

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

I'm new to database and Oracle, but I need to learn it.

I just following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/venturenxt/install-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04-c081d51c0f9d) to install **Oracle 12c**, I almost on at the end of the steps.

I have finishing install the database with GUI interface, and now I want to start the database that I have installed with this following command:

`sqlplus /nolog`

and yea, I have entered to the database, and then I run this following command to connect as **sys**:
`connect sys as sysdba`

But it prompt **Enter password:**

Unfortunately, I don't know what is the default password for that.

I have try the password with **CHANGE_ON_ INSTALL** base on this following [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/win.920/a95490/username.htm), but it seems not work actually.

[image]

So, what is the default password..?, or any way to bypass that password and then change it if I forgot..?

**EDIT:** I following @Tejash----ORA-00980 instructions to use this command to directly log into DB as a **sysdba**:

`sqlplus / as sysdba`

And the result is like this:
[image]
What username should I use..?, I have try it with **sys** and **sysdba** but it still prompt a **Enter password:**

**EDIT 2:** Here is my **sqlnet.ora** and **tnsnames.ora** files
[image]
and here is my **$ORACLE_SID** and **$ORACLE_HOME** values.
[image]

Comment: You get an ORA-12547, so I assume the problem is not caused by wrong password. In Oracle 12 there is no default password, you (or whoever created the database) has to provide the initial password when the database is created.

Comment: Hi Man @WernfriedDomscheit, I have edited my questions, can you help me with that please..?

Comment: No, it prompts you for a new username, i.e. sqlplus asks for a new connection to a new database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the same system where Oracle database is installed and you have logged in to the system using a correct privileged user then you can bypass the password.

> Please note that the path of the ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID is
>   properly configured. Also, TNSLISTNER and SQLNET files are properly
>   configured.

You can directly log into DB as a sysdba using the following command:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have try to following your intructions, and I post the result on my edited questions, please check it out :)

Comment: Can you please post your SQLNET.ora and TNSNAMES.ora files?
Also, Please share the values of ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID?

Comment: I have made new EDIT 2, please check it out :)

Comment: Are you sure $ORACLE_SID is correct?

Comment: How to check if the path is correct..?
I just following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/venturenxt/install-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04-c081d51c0f9d
on # Oracle Settings sections.

Comment: Set `PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` 
----------- Also, I am considering that your `ORACLE_SID` is `SID`. You can try with `orcl` as your ORACLE_SID(which is the default at the time of installation)

Comment: It still give me a prompt of "Enter password:"

Comment: I think recreate your password file will help
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba007.htm

Just have in mind if it is a production box, backup it up before to recreate it.